# How to split in Pandas cells with multiple data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to extract data from this output (multiplied by 23 col but i will do on a post basis):

```
                         0                                                                                             22
2014  {'tag': 'operatingrevenue', 'value': 182795000}                      

[1 rows x 23 columns]
```

How can I extract in order to have a table, indexed by years, with the columns populated with the 'tag' and the values as the relative value of that tag?

```
     |   operatingrevenue   

2014 |      182795000
```

I specify that i'm working with pandas and python 3.7

Thanks

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Could you update your question with an example dataframe, so that we can help.

Comment: Done, thanks a lot to everyone. I'm struggling since 2 days, i tried to do it on my own but i don't know what to look for.

Comment: That original sample data isnt very clear. can you update?

Comment: It should be clearer now. I have 23 columns but i will work on those with a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this data is representative of your case, it should work:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:  [{'tag': 'operatingrevenue', 'value': 182795000},
                        {'tag': 'operatingrevenue', 'value': 182796000}],
                   1:  [{'tag': 'cashdividendspershare', 'value': 1.82},
                        {'tag': 'cashdividendspershare', 'value': 1.92}]},
                  index=[2014, 2015])

df.columns = [i['tag'] for i in df.iloc[0].values]

df = df.applymap(lambda x: x['value'])

df

      operatingrevenue  cashdividendspershare
2014         182795000                   1.82
2015         182796000                   1.92
```